# How could I detect that ROS is installed in CMakeLists

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I need to make universal CMakeLists.txt, able to build package with ROS or not.
So I need some conditional variable to detect, that package could be build with ROS:

```
if(SOMEVAR)
   set(USE_ROS true)
endif()

if(USE_ROS)
   find_package ...
   catkin_package ...
endif()
```

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267578/how-could-i-detect-that-ros-is-installed-in-cmakelists/) by [Rr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2748/rr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2017-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

find_package creates a _FOUND variable for packages instead of an error if you don't use REQUIRED.

Try:

```
find_package(catkin COMPONENTS ...)

if( $catkin_FOUND )
    # Build with ROS
endif()
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-28**:
Possibly related: #q230877.